# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trackPid' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, twitter, undefined

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/oct.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof twttr!=='undefined' && twttr && typeof twttr.conversion==='function' && typeof twttr.conversion.trackPid==='function'){
   twttr.conversion.trackPid('xxxx',{tw_sale_amount:0,tw_order_quantity:0});
        }
            </script>
```

I have a this twitter tracker code, I've tried a lot of ways but i can not resolve the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trackPid' of undefined"

Sometimes it gives this error. I have been see this error with my JavaScript error logger, how can i fix this error absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to provide you a proper answer as we can't see how your twttr is instantiated. You probably import it via an HTML script tag I guess.

Anyway the error means that the the property conversion is undefined for your object, so either the object is not instantiated at all, or the property is not the right one.

Maybe if your object is not always available for some reason just change your test or add another test like if(twtrr) or if (twtrr.conversion) which equals twtrr !== undefined. It will avoid having the error but your code will not be executed.